# Wireshark Dissector :- Running autogen.sh and configure again

Tags: wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to write the basic plugin for wireshark.
I wrote the basic # foo # dissector(packet-foo.c) as per

> https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectAdd.html

and then I added and Modified all the file as per

> doc/README.plugins

After Modifying all the files It says to Run autogen.sh.
I run it on my command prompt like

> C:\Development\Wireshark>./autogen.sh

It says

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

** Am I missing something ? **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something ?

Yes, you're missing the fact that Windows and UN*Xes are different operating systems with different toolchains and different build systems, which means that the autotools (automake, autoconf, etc.) aren't used on Windows. :-)

And `README.plugins` is missing that fact as well. :-( I've filed [Wireshark bug 11236](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11236) on that.

Try just running `nmake -f Makefile.nmake` in the top-level directory.